# Why does abstract class have to implement all methods from interface?

Tags: typescript

```
interface BaseInter {
  name: string;
  test(): void;
}
    
abstract class Abs implements BaseInter { }
```

In TypeScript, compiler complaints that the class incorrectly implements the interface:

> name is missing in type Abs.

Here `Abs` is an abstract class and so why do we need to implement the interface over there?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to re-write all of the members/methods in the interface and add the `abstract` keyword to them, so in your case:

```
interface baseInter {
    name: string;
    test();
}

abstract class abs implements baseInter {
    abstract name: string;
    abstract test();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20baseInter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20abs%20implements%20baseInter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20test()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

There was a suggestion for it: [Missing property declaration in abstract class implementing interfaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4670) but it was declined for this reason:

> Although, the convenience of not writing the declaration would be
>   nice, the possible confusion/complexity arising from this change would
>   not warrant it. by examine the declaration, it is not clear which
>   members appear on the type, is it all properties, methods, or
>   properties with call signatures; would they be considered abstract?
>   optional?

Answer (score 13):

You can get what you want with a slight trick that defeats the compile-time errors:

```
interface baseInter {
    name : string;
    test();
}

interface abs extends baseInter {}

abstract class abs implements baseInter{
}
```

This trick takes advantage of Typescript's [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), and was originally presented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4670#issuecomment-326585615) and posted on a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671334/2540235).

Comment: Be careful though. There is no error if properties or methods are not implemented in the inherited class. So even an empty inherited class would be valid in this case.

Comment: But it works as intended when baseInter is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are used for defining a contract regarding the shape of an object.

Use constructor to pass in properties to the class

```
interface BaseInter {
  name : string;
  test(): boolean;
}

abstract class Abs implements BaseInter {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
  test(): boolean {
    throw new Error('Not implemented')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Base` is an interface (as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52373394/3546290)), there is no error in `Derived`. But if `Base` is an abstract class, it works as intended.

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract name: string;
  abstract test(): void;
}

interface Abstract extends Base { }
abstract class Abstract { }

class Derived extends Abstract {
  // ERROR: Non-abstract class 'Derived' does not implement inherited abstract member 'name' from class 'Abstract'.
  // ERROR: Non-abstract class 'Derived' does not implement inherited abstract member 'test' from class 'Abstract'.
}
```

It feels hacky for me, but as for Typescript 4.9.5 it works.