# Typescript declaration: Merge a class and an interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, declaration, ambient

I have two models `Model` and its subclass `ClientModel` an ambient module. Now I want to declare a set of attributes of `ClientModel` from an interface so called `Client`. How can I do it? I can imagine something like this:

```
interface Client {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

declare class ClientModel extends Model implements Client {
    // with name and email here without redeclare them
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use declaration merging. If the class and the interface are declared in the same namespace/module and have the same name, they will be merged into a single class type.

```
interface ClientModel {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

class ClientModel extends Model  {
    m() {
        this.email //Valid 
    }
}
```

If you cannot change the interface or is declared in another namespace and you can't move it you can inherit from it in the merged interface:

```
interface Client {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

interface ClientModel extends Client {}
class ClientModel extends Model  {
    m() {
        this.email //Valid 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Titian, let me know if I should ask a new question. Is there a way I can add a static property to the base Model. I got a TS2300 when I try to merge the declaration...

Comment: When do you get the error? when trying to add a static property ? Merging only works in some cases, interface + class is one, class + class will not work, and interfaces can't have statics

Comment: Exactly, The class (Model) is from an ambient module that I do not control. I can easily merge with a set of instance properties (e.g. `instance.name`) the way you show me but not for a static one (e.g `Model.toJSON()`.) You said that "class + class will not work" which is the case...

Comment: For the second approach, it works fine, but I get this linter error: "An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface". Any idea how to address this?

Comment: @Ben that is a lint rule and it is wrong in this case. Just ignore it. Lint rules are not 100% right.