# How to create a util for the class

Tags: typescript, vue-class-components

**What I have done**
My initial approach is to use the following mixin that returns a class decorator:

```
function createMixin (behaviour: any, sharedBehaviour: any = {}): any {
  const instanceKeys: any = Reflect.ownKeys(behaviour)
  const sharedKeys: any = Reflect.ownKeys(sharedBehaviour)
  const typeTag = Symbol(`isa`)

  function _mixin (clazz: Function): Function {
    for (let property of instanceKeys) {
      Object.defineProperty(clazz.prototype, property, {
        value: behaviour[property],
        writable: true
      })
    }

    Object.defineProperty(clazz.prototype, typeTag, { value: true })

    return clazz
  }

  for (let property of sharedKeys) {
    Object.defineProperty(_mixin, property, {
      value: sharedBehaviour[property],
      enumerable: sharedBehaviour.propertyIsEnumerable(property)
    })
  }

  Object.defineProperty(_mixin, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: (i: any) => !!i[typeTag]
  })

  return _mixin
}

export const customUtil = createMixin({
  customUtil (event: any) {
    console.log(this)
  }
})
```

So later the util can be used to decorate the class and can access this of the target class without any problem:

```
import { customUtil } from 'utils'

@customUtil
export default class ComponentClass extends Vue {
  someClassMethod() {
    this.customUtil() // successfully outputs the whole class in the console
  }
}
```

**But** it results in the tslinter warning `TS2339: Property 'customUtil' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass'.`

**Questions**
1. Is there a possibility to resolve the linter issue by somehow "typing" the method assigned to the class by the mixin utility 
2. If there is an alternative approach to have utility functions/classes that will have no issue to access this of the class they are used in and with a simple way of attaching them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed in [other Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813329/adding-properties-to-a-class-via-decorators-in-typescript) and is also a [pending issue in the TypeScript github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881). But there are two ways to get around this.

**1: Typecasting**

You could just typecast `this` to either forget the class Context or enhance it with the nescessary information.

```
import { customUtil } from 'utils'

@customUtil
export default class ComponentClass extends Vue {
  someClassMethod() {
    (this as any).customUtil(); // Now the linter will be fine but you will lose type safety
    (this as any as {customUtil: (event:any) => void}).customUtil(); // This works and you could/should extract the type. 
  }
}
```

But as you can see, this is not ideal.

**2: Real TypeScript Mixins**

You could use real TypeScript Mixins instead of Decorators:

*Utils*

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

// The Mixin
export function WithUtils<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {
    customUtil (event?: any) { // Actually, 'event' needs to be optional
      console.log(this)
    }
  };
}

// A Base class so you can just extend if needed
export const UtilsBase = WithUtils(class {});
```

*Component*

```
export default class ComponentClass extends WithUtils(Vue) {
  someClassMethod() {
    this.customUtil() // successfully outputs the whole class in the console
  }
}
```

*Class not extending from Vue*

```
export default class SomeClass extends UtilsBase {
  someClassMethod() {
    this.customUtil() // successfully outputs the whole class in the console
  }
}

// alternatively, you can use the Mixin with an unnamed class
export default class SomeClass extends WithUtils(class {}) {
  someClassMethod() {
    this.customUtil() // successfully outputs the whole class in the console
  }
}
```

Comment: Pascal thank you very much for the help, I took me on some road of researching but eventually I came back to idea you suggest here. Wish you all the best :-)

Comment: Only felt into small issue with `Cannot find name 'T'.` for the `type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T` can you please suggest a possible workaround? :-)

Comment: I have tried to declare `declare module 'T' {
  const T: any
  export = T
}` but now luck for now :)

Comment: @volna Glad it helped! :) For your problem: `T` is not a Module but a generic. It should compile as is. Which TypeScript Version are you using?

Comment: Right now the project is using `3.5.3` :-)

Comment: 3.5.3 can definitely handle generics - TypeScript Playground goes back to 2.4.1 and even that can handle it... Strange. Did you change that line somehow? What does it say when you copy-paste it to TypeScript Playground? I'm a bit out of ideas as the code I posted does work on playground...

Comment: I have double checked the code and you are absolutely right, I actually modified the line :shy: thank you once again Pascal :)